# select option problem on saving on database codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this select option problem on saving to database

here's my code

```
<div class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right">
                <div id="loantype">
                    <select class="form-group loan_type" id="loan_type form-field-2" name="loan_type" value="<?php echo set_value('loan_type');?>" required>
                        <option value="0">Select Loan Type</option>
                        <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                    </select>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right">
                <div class="personalloan" id="personalloan" style="display:none">
                    <select class="form-group loan_amount" id="loan_amount form-field-2" name="loan_amount" value="<?php echo set_value('loan_amount');?>" required>
                        <option value="0">Select Loan Amount</option>
                        <option value="10000">P10,000</option>
                        <option value="20000">P20,000</option>
                        <option value="30000">P30,000</option>
                    </select>   
                </div>
                <div class="businessloan" id="businessloan" style="display:none">
                    <select class="form-group loan_amount" id="loan_amount form-field-2" name="loan_amount" value="<?php echo set_value('loan_amount');?>" required>
                        <option value="0">Select Loan Amount</option>
                        <option value="10000">P10,000</option>
                        <option value="20000">P20,000</option>
                        <option value="30000">P30,000</option>
                        <option value="40000">P40,000</option>
                        <option value="50000">P50,000</option>
                    </select>   
                </div>
```

as you can see when I select the `loan_type` for example `personal` then this `personalloan` will show up

```
<div class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right">
                <div class="personalloan" id="personalloan" style="display:none">
                    <select class="form-group loan_amount" id="loan_amount form-field-2" name="loan_amount" value="<?php echo set_value('loan_amount');?>" required>
                        <option value="0">Select Loan Amount</option>
                        <option value="10000">P10,000</option>
                        <option value="20000">P20,000</option>
                        <option value="30000">P30,000</option>
                    </select>   
                </div>
```

same goes with the `Business` if I choose that the `businessloan` will show up . But the problem is that only the datas from select option `businessloan` is being saved on the database but when I choose something on the `personalloan` its always 0.

I save it like this

```
'loan_type' => $this->input->post('loan_type'),
'loan_amount' => $this->input->post('loan_amount'),
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: Your selects have the same ID `loan_amount form-field-2` which is not allowed. Change the name of one of them and the logic to figure out which one you need to retrieve and save.

Comment: You mentioned the same name (loan_amount) in two select option.Change the name in any one select option.

Comment: Just because you are hiding the select doesnt mean its data is not sent. Since your business loan one is the second one, that will get sent to the server and read. It will overwrite the value of the first select with the same name.

Comment: so on my save it will look like this ? ```'loan_amount' => $this->input->post('loan_amount'),loan_amount' => $this->input->post('loan_amount2')```

Comment: Key names in an array must also be unique.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so basically I need to add a 1 more field on my database?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you only want one of the two values when the form is submitted, or do you want to keep both?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are correct . I need only one value to be inserted on the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with some issues.

- You have the same `id` on multiple elements. `id`'s' *must* be unique withing the document.
- You have the same `name` on both the select, which will make one overwrite the other when the form is posted

So let's start by chaning the names and ids:

```
<!-- The personal select -->
<select class="form-group loan_amount" id="loan_amount_personal" name="loan_amount_personal" required>

<!-- The business select -->
<select class="form-group loan_amount" id="loan_amount_business" name="loan_amount_business" required>
```

*You might need to update any references in your javascript with the new id's, if you have any.*

Then, when the form is posted, you get the select you want, depending on the type:

```
$amount = null;

if ($this->input->post('loan_type') === 'Personal') {
    $amount = $this->input->post('loan_amount_personal');
} else {
    $amount = $this->input->post('loan_amount_business');    
}

// Or for short:
$amount = $this->input->post('loan_type') === 'Personal'
    ? $this->input->post('loan_amount_personal')
    : $this->input->post('loan_amount_business');
```

And then, when building the array:

```
'loan_type'   => $this->input->post('loan_type'),
'loan_amount' => $amount,
```

Comment: Sorry but i still get 0

Comment: @BoonMingProg - Sorry, I made a typo. I was comparing against `personal` instead of `Personal`. I've updated the answer. Try the updated PHP-code.

Comment: Thank you . Sir Can I add 1 more question

Comment: @BoonMingProg - Ask away.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen you have same name  given personalloan and businessloan.(input type name).Please give Different name.and In input id in always one argument pass.